# How can I send a welcome email to newly registered users in Rails using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, registration, devise

I am using Devise on Rails and I'm wondering if there is a hook or a filter that I can use to add a bit of code to Devise's user registration process and send a welcome email to the user after an account has been created. Without Devise it would be something like this...

```
  respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        Notifier.welcome_email(@user).deliver    # <======= 
  ...
```

Comment: Are you using Devise's confirmable method ?

Comment: Funny you should ask that because I'm having trouble with that method. It doesn't send out the email, even though my configuration works. No, for the welcome email I am using my own method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this by using a callback method. It's not the cleanest of solutions, not as clean as an observer, but I'll take it. I'm lucky Mongoid implemented the ActiveRecord callbacks!

```
  after_create :send_welcome_mail
  def send_welcome_mail
     Contact.welcome_email(self.email, self.name).deliver
  end
```

Comment: How can I send the welcome message "after" it has confirmed the account? (in restful_authentication there was a method called recently_activated?)

Comment: There is a similar method in Devise. http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirmed%3F-instance_method

Comment: picardo: Actually that only check if it's confirmed or not. I had to actually overwrite the confirm! method: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/812#comment_1113176

Comment: A tangential note, isn't it weird that the name welcome_**email** looks ok on a mailer object, ideally it should be named **welcome**, as the mailer is used only to send out emails. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the callback style, as I discuss below. That style has fallen out of favor.

Comment: I don't like this way because it'll always send the email, even if you create the user in the console or an admin interface. I would only want a user to get that kind of mail if they're expecting it.

Comment: I feel like this is a good method if you are NOT using confirmable and just need a dead simple way to send out an email after the user signs up. In my case it works because only an admin can approve the user.

Answer (score 32):

The next most popular answer assumes you're using using Devise's :confirmable module, which I'm not.

I didn't like the other solutions because you have to use model callbacks, which will always send welcome emails even when you create his account in the console or an admin interface. My app involves the ability to mass-import users from a CSV file. I don't want my app sending a surprise email to all 3000 of them one by one, but I do want users who create their own account to get a welcome email.
The solution:

1) Override Devise's Registrations controller:

```
#registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    UserMailer.welcome(resource).deliver unless resource.invalid?
  end

end
```

2) Tell Devise you overrode its Registrations controller:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Comment: I like this approach, it's clean, doesn't take much code, and the logic of it is obvious. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: This one seems to be the best solution.

Comment: How do you know that `@user` is available?

Comment: In my experience, overriding devise controller actions leads to nothing but pain and suffering. Even something that seems so innocuous as this has caused me upgrade pains. It seems to be a snowballing action where you override one method. That one override suddenly requires you to override another method and so on.

Comment: @JeffGandt I think you'd be hard-pressed to find anyone who's ended up in a snowballing mess after implementing this solution

Answer (score 10):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6133991/109618 shows a decent (not perfect) answer, but at least better than ones I'm seeing here. It overrides the `confirm!` method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise # ...
  # ...
  def confirm!
    welcome_message # define this method as needed
    super
  end
  # ...
end
```

This is better because it does not use callbacks. Callbacks are not great to the extent that they (1) make models hard to test; (2) put too much logic into models. Overusing them often means you have behavior in a model that belongs elsewhere. For more discussion on this, see: [Pros and cons of using callbacks for domain logic in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039023/pros-and-cons-of-using-callbacks-for-domain-logic-in-rails).

The above approach ties into the `confirm!` method, which is preferable to a callback for this example. Like a callback though, the logic is still in the model. :( So I don't find the approach fully satisfactory.

Comment: I don't know how this can be better, because mailer is part of controller, not model. Simpler, but wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using a [ActiveRecord::Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).  The idea with the observer is that you would create a class with an `after_save` method that would call the notification.  All you need to do is create the observer class and then modify the application configuration to register the observer.  The documentation describes the process quite well.

Using the observer pattern means you do not need to change any logic in the controller.

Comment: I'm using Mongoid. Is it still possible to use an ActiveRecord observer?

Comment: Well looking at http://blog.eizesus.com/2010/03/creating-a-rails-authentication-system-on-mongoid-part-2-7-3-2010/ it does not seem that there is observer support.  Your after_create call back seems to be seems to me to be the best way

Answer (score 2):

Since a `yield` has been added to the Devise controller methods a while back, I think this is now probably the best way to do it.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super do |resource|
      Notifier.welcome_email(resource).deliver if resource.persisted?
    end  
  end

end
```